# Using form parameters within a Wordpress "Page"

Tags: forms

I've created a landing "page" on a Wordpress website which will be receiving a form post from another website. Is there a simple way within the Wordpress editor to look for the existence of a specific form parameter and write it out with a shortcut on the page?

Further to this, is there a way to perhaps add some conditional statements?

e.g.

```
If FORM_PARAMETER = "YES" 
    //Write "success" to the screen.
```

Just to confirm, this isn't something I intend on writing in a PHP file, rather it would have to be within the page editor.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: You are going to need to use PHP here. A shortcode sounds like the way to go.